# Windows Azure WorkerRole response

Tags: c#, azure, azure-worker-roles

I am working on an Azure demo to run Powershell in a worker role. In my web role I add the name of the Powershell script which is to be run to a CloudQueue object.

I can print the script output to the debug console but need to be able to get this output back into my web role and display it on the ASP.NET page.

Any suggestions on how this is done?

Comment: I don't understand the question. How would you get the output back to your web role if you were running a batch file? Or a Windows service processing messages from MSMQ? Or a long-running console application? How does PowerShell make this scenario any different from any other message passing system? In other words: this isn't a PowerShell question.

Comment: I'd love to learn more about what you're trying to do and how.  I'm going to try to learn more about Azure programming in the next two weeks.

Comment: You're right Peter, this isn't a PowerShell question so I've removed the tag.
Marco, unfortunately I can't give any details but essentially the application should run PowerShell scripts on a worker role when the user clicks a button for example.  I have it specifying the powershell script to run through the message queue, but I need to get the output back from the script (for errors etc).  I'm thinking I need to use a cloud storage container.

Comment: Again, a novice here, I wonder if you will want to/need to (or it may be easier) to use a custom PowerShell runspace to invoke the script.

Comment: The Azure SDK comes with an example that shows how to invoke the script.  As far as I could tell, the RunspaceFactory class isn't available within Azure roles (I could be wrong).  What the sample does is create a class library that acts as a wrapper around the RunspaceFactory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazuresamples

It has a PowerShell worker role sample, that I have currently running here currently:
http://marcoposh.cloudapp.net/

A brief explanation is here:
http://marcoshaw.blogspot.com/2009/12/running-powershell-in-cloud-with-azure.html